# Configuring Twitter Passport in Node to Allow Authenticated Users to Post Tweets

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, oauth

Hi I'm wondering how to configure the passport-twitter npm package to allow authenticated users to post tweets from the app I'm currently building, using their own twitter account.

Also, are their node packages that are more suited to using twitter functionality that requires access tokens? Like this?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-twitter-token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passport is only for oauth, i.e to signup/signin via strategy like twitter. its not to use the twitter API as whole.

However on signup/signin you can use the token , to communicate with twitter independently. If you go out for third party modules, then I doubt you will not find one which smoothly co-exist with passport. they may have their own handles.

For facebook strategy I did the same. I have not used any third party module. instead I directly called facebook Graph API using http request and passed the same token which passport has given me and I was successfully able to post stories on facebook wall using that token.